# Csrf token is sometimes filled as an attribute in a rails 6 form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

I have a strange case I can not figure out - sometimes a form field is filled with a csrf_token

1. People are enrolling in a group.
2. The form contains enroll[group_user][group_id].

It looks like this

```
<form data-target="groups-enroll.form" action="/teach/groups/636191/enrolls" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">

 <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="ntKeXi34N7Ob6u7K4K4cgifKp22MNNyFOTz/ocQQlbVHnEnT+n/aLZlEfBYu/lqgN2qhdpjwdXXNdkY36TB//A==">
 <input type="hidden" value="636191" name="enroll[group_user_attributes][group_id]" id="enroll_group_user_attributes_group_id">
```

Sometimes, like exactly four times in the last month when the form is submitted the value of group_id is

```
"enroll": {
  "group_user_attributes": {
    "group_id": "x96KqNDRLhUhwWgQpf1c/x5puCXpLeiD+/Ym2gm3auRRBZsaVOw2rCpauziCJGmepsP6ueiBud/8ItW5JUhLxg==",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Why would that be. Why would the group_id field have a csrf_token?

The input field is generated with:

```
 <%= f.fields_for :group_user, {parent_builder: f} do |group_user_form| %>
        <%= group_user_form.hidden_field :group_id %>
```

I can not figure out how com in these 4 cases the id for the group was replaced with a token?

First time it occurred it did not bothered me. But it is happening like once a week for the last 4 weeks (compared to having hundreds of successful enrollments) so I think there is something I am missing here.

Thanks

**Update 1**

It seems to be a firefox issue. On firefox the field for group_id is filled with a strange value
[image]

**Update 2**
Reporting to firefox as a bug - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1667657